# Banach Space as the direct sum of a line with another subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\mathcal B$ be Banach. Let $z \in \mathcal B$ be non-zero. Consider $A = \operatorname{span}(\{z\})$. Is it possible to find a closed subspace $C$ such that $$\mathcal B = A \oplus C?$$

If so, how would one proceed to do so? If $\mathcal B$ is also Hilbert, then this would be $C = z^\perp$. Though, it's not clear how this is done in general.

If it is possible, I'm looking for a small **hint** not a full answer.

Comment: Do you know the Hahn-Banach Theorem?

Comment: @David Mhm, so I thought it would make sense to have $C$ be the kernel of some functional

Comment: Is that a yes? ${}$

Comment: @David But I don't get how the extension to all of $\mathcal B$ would necessarily vanish, maybe $ \alpha z \mapsto \alpha$

& yes

Comment: Why don't you try writing something down with Hahn-Banach and see how far you get.

Comment: @David Should i be considering the mapping $\alpha z \mapsto \alpha$?

Comment: Yes. On what subspace? And then what?

Comment: @David defined on $A$. Then I'd assume that the extension had to vanish on the rest for if not I don't think it would be linear...and the extension has operator norm $\|z\|^{-1}$ but I don't know if that's relevant

Comment: So you use Hahn-Banach to extend the functional to a continuous linear functional on all of $B$, right? You don't need to worry about whether it's linear, because Hahn-Banach guarantees it. The norm is relevant in this problem only in that its finiteness guarantees the continuity of the extension. You mentioned the kernel. Try proving that the kernel and $A$ are supplementary.

Comment: @David Well the kernel is all things that look like $y-F(y)z$ since $F$ is linear so then we can just write $y = y-F(y)z+F(y)z$?

Comment: That is the right decomposition. You still need to prove that $y - F(y)z$ really is in the kernel. That proves that the sum of the two subspaces                                           is the whole space. Second, you need to check that the two subspaces have trivial intersection. Lastly, why is the kernel closed?

Comment: @David I got it. Thank you kindly David.

Answer (score 1):

For any linear functional $f$ on $X$ and any $z\notin \ker f$, we have 
$$X=\operatorname{span}(z)\oplus \ker f$$
via the explicit isomorphism
$$
x\mapsto \left( \frac{f(x)}{f(z)}z, \ x - \frac{f(x)}{f(z)}z \right)
$$
the inverse of which is $(a,b)\mapsto a+b$.

Thus, given $z$, one only needs $f$ such that $f(z)\ne 0$; the Hahn-Banach theorem delivers that (and more).

One says that every one-dimensional subspace is *complemented* in $X$.